# 501 Not Implemented error when making request to localhost

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4, mpm-event

I'm using `apache mpm event` and `php-fpm` on my CentOS 8 server. I need to be able to make http requests from my server to a php api on my server, so the url of the api would be something like: `http://127.0.0.1/~<account_name>/api.php`. there is no problem with the url and the php file gets found on the server, but it generates a `501 Not Implemented` error.

what is causing this error when I try to make http requests to localhost and how to solve the issue?

Comment: There is no way to know without seeing anything about your configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider so what configurations may cause it? apache or php?

Comment: Both are possibilities

Comment: @GeraldSchneider there are many php extensions and apache modules installed and configured. do you have any hint for me which may be possibilities of the issue to look into?